# Google Sheets Query Function not recognizing HEXADECIMAL number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, hex, worksheet

On a 'testing' worksheet I have a formula in cell B4 that does what I want.

That being:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,('11 - PI Codes'!A2:A521),1,false), "PI Code is NOT in use")

It references a worksheet to find appearances, if they exist, of a 4 digit hexadecimal PI code number.

I want to use a function to generate a table where data (columns & rows) associated with the hexadecimal PI code number is in use, to populate on a worksheet. I can generate a table (it works), but only if value in cell B4 looks like a decimal number.

The closest function I have found that comes close to doing what I want, so far is the QUERY function. But I have two problems with it.

1. It does not recognise hexadecimal numbers or at least a number with characters A to F
2. The query function works okay with a decimal value in a referenced cell on the same worksheet where the query function is written. This is the query function that I wrote, but that only works for a number using only digits 0 to 9

   =query('11 - PI Codes'!A1:I521, "SELECT A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I WHERE A=" &B4, 1)
   The above formula is located on 'testing' worksheet.
   The above columns A & B are hexadecimal numbers (4 & 2 digit respectively), columns C to F are text, column G is a decimal number eg 99.5 etc.

I'm not skilled in script writing (zero) knowledge & only tiny knowledge of functions.

Any & all assistance would be highly appreciated to help me solve my problem.

I tried usage of '"&B4&"'" in the query function, with a cell B3 input of FFFF hexadecimal number (used in cell B4 output, but query function only returned the header when a table of several FFFF entries ideally should have been returned.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY can only deal with one type of data per column. If you are actually receiving data when entering numbers, probably the ones containing letters are being dismissed. You can try adding single quotation marks like this surrounding B4:

```
=query('11 - PI Codes'!A1:I521, "SELECT A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I WHERE A='" &B4&"'", 1)
```

But if it doesn't work, you can try with FILTER:

```
=FILTER({'11 - PI Codes'!A1:A521,'11 - PI Codes'!C1:I521},'11 - PI Codes'!A1:A521=B4)
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks Martin. The first option with the Query function didn't work, but the FILTER function did.

Comment: It was probable that it wouldn't work, because of the types of data limitation of QUERY function. I'm glad the other option did work! Consider marking the question as answered 